# What kind of component can be added on Watch OS Sprite Kit node and how?

Tags: sprite-kit, watchos

How can you add a custom component to SKNodes on a project with one target with watchOS?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please have a look at other good/popular questions in order to get a grasp about how a good question should look like. Also, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask may guide you in writing a clear and concise question that can be answered. In the current state, your question most likely won't be answered.

Answer (score 1):

You only can add custom components, creating a new class extended a `GKComponent` for example:

```
import GameplayKit

class NewGameComponent: GKComponent {

}
```

Then you can see the component in the list like this:

[image]

You can download an example here: https://github.com/Maetschl/SpriteKitExamples/tree/master/ComponentTest

The WatchOS target are not related to the question.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The WatchOS target is related to my question because my project is for watch. The Watch OS doesn’t have GameplayKit library. The GameplayKit is only available for iOS, macOS, Mac Catalyst and tvOS. So, I can not use GKComponent.
So my questions stands: What kind of component can be added on watch os if GKComponent can not be use.

Comment: True, my mistake! GameplayKit doesn't have support on WatchOS.